# Orbit followed by a particle around Schwarzschild Black Hole

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex, astronomy

The following is a equation which describes various possible orbits of a particle around the Schwarzschild black hole spacetime in general relativity. I want to solve it from `-Pi` to `Pi` but fails, any suggestions?

```
d = 6 m; m = 2;

s = 
  NDSolve[
    {u'[ϕ] - Sqrt[2 m u[ϕ]^3 - u[ϕ]^2 + 1/d^2] == 0, u[0] == 0}, 
    u, {ϕ, -0.4, 2.5}]


P1 = PolarPlot[Evaluate[{1/(u[ϕ])} /. s], {ϕ, -0.4, 2.5},AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: this produces a plot fine for me. You may want to specify an aspect ratio eg, `AspectRatio -> 1` to `PolarPlot`

Comment: Yes. Actualy, what I am getting after running the programme is not clear.

Comment: I added the plot to the question. Its not clear if you aren't seeing a plot or if you think something is wrong with the plot.

Comment: What if we use the range for  \phi from -\pi to + \pi.

Comment: What is the source of the ode?

Comment: This programme is for the orbit followed by a particle around Schwarzschild Black Hole.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to `PolarPlot` `u[ϕ]`? Isn't `u=1/r`?

Comment: Here u=1/r. The final output is the polar plot between r and \phi.

Comment: Are you sure the equation is correct? How did you deduce it?

Comment: Yes. The equation is correct. This is a standard equation which describes various possible orbits of a particle around the Schwarzschild black hole spacetime in general relativity.

Comment: Can you add a reference for the equation?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.4068.pdf ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution 1

The equation can be solved with `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`, together with a higher `WorkingPrecision`:

```
d = 6 m; m = 2;
s = NDSolve[{u'[ϕ] - Sqrt[2 m u[ϕ]^3 - u[ϕ]^2 + 1/d^2] == 0, u[0] == 0}, 
  u, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 64]

Plot[Evaluate[u[ϕ] /. s // Re], {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[1/u[ϕ] /. s // Re], {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PolarPlot[Evaluate[1/u[ϕ] /. s // Re], {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> ϕ == 0,
  PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I added `Re` because even with `WorkingPrecision -> 64` the solution still involves very small imaginary numeric error e.g.

```
s[[1, 1, -1]][-Pi]
(* -0.0736592722609752787242287643805033631850830491206634648394182567 - 
 4.668866930386631320069097140978040*10^-31 I *)
```

## Solution 2

Inspired by **Solution 1**, I found the problem can be resolved by adding a `Re` in the equation:

```
d = 6 m; m = 2;
s = NDSolve[{u'[ϕ] - Re@Sqrt[2 m u[ϕ]^3 - u[ϕ]^2 + 1/d^2] == 0, 
   u[0] == 0}, u, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}]
```

The resulting graph is the same as above so I'd like to omit it here.

## P.S.

I still have a feeling that the equation is wrong, at least incomplete, for example, don't you think the following

```
d = 6 m; m = 2;
s = NDSolve[{u'[ϕ]^2 == (Re@Sqrt[2 m u[ϕ]^3 - u[ϕ]^2 + 1/d^2])^2, 
   u[0] == 0}, u, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}]

PolarPlot[Evaluate[1/u[ϕ] /. s], {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> ϕ == 0, 
 PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

seems to be more natural?

Comment: Now this is fine. Its working now. Thank you very much xzczd.