# Why NDSolve has problem with Gamma[5/2,0,x]?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, special-functions

I was trying to solve three arrays of Poisson's equation with three different incomplete gamma functions and 10 different initial conditions for each. I did the following (taking my first array as an example):

```
ϵ = 10^-6
G1[x_] := Exp[x] Gamma[3/2, 0, x]
T1 = {ψ[i]''[r] + 2/r ψ[i]'[r] == -9*G1[ψ[i][r]]/G1[i]}
T2 = {ψ[i][ϵ] == i}
T3 = {ψ[i]'[ϵ] == 0}
eqn1 = Join[T1, T2, T3]
psi1 = Table[NDSolve[eqn1, ψ[i], {r, ϵ, 20}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Then I just repeated the above for Gamma[5/2, 0, x] and Gamma[7/2, 0, x]. The first and third array worked fine, but I couldn't get the equations solved for Gamma[5/2, 0, x]. There was no warnings, the programme just kept running. It seems like I have to narrow down my domain to around `{r, ϵ, 2}`. Is there something special about this gamma function that made the computation complicated, or is there any flaw with my codes that created a pitfall at this point?

Comment: It should be :`G1[x_] := Exp[x] Gamma[3/2, 0, x]`

Comment: There is a discontinuity in the imaginary part of the principal value of `Gamma[5/2, 0, z]` along the negative real axis.  See http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.3.F15.mag or `Plot3D[Im@Gamma[5/2, 0, x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`.  When the solution becomes negative, the approximate floating point calculations might jump back and forth because of the sign change in the discontinuity, which for `5/2` is the opposite of `3/2`, `7/2`.

Answer (score 4):

For $a = (2n+1)/2$, the incomplete gamma function $\gamma(a,z)$ has two branches,

```
Gamma[a, 0, x + I y]
Exp[-2 Pi I * a] Gamma[a, 0, x + I y] (* yes, this is just  -Gamma[a, 0 x + I y],
                                         but I kept the general form to play with  a  *)
```

which are branched along the negative real axis (see [DLMF (8.2.8)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E8)):

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   *Real and imaginary parts of $\gamma(a,z)$* for $a=\textstyle{3\over2},{5\over2},{7\over2}$.
>
> ```
> GraphicsGrid[
>  Table[
>   Plot3D[
>    {part[Gamma[a, 0, x + I y]],
>     part[Exp[-2 Pi I *a] Gamma[a, 0, x + I y]]},
>    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
>    PlotLabel -> 
>     With[{p = part, a = a}, 
>      HoldForm[p@γ[Style[a, Small], x + I y]]], 
>    ViewPoint -> {-2.5, 2, 1.2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, part@γ}],
>   {part, {Re, Im}}, {a, {3/2, 5/2, 7/2}}],
>  ImageSize -> 800
>  ]
> ```

The biggest problem is that each IVP drives the solution `ψ[r]` down the positive real axis through though the branch point in `γ[a, ψ[r]]` at `ψ[r] == 0`.  The question is on what branch to exit the branch point?  Either seems equally valid.  A way to choose the branch is presented further down, after we introduce the notion of a winding number.

Assuming one wants to avoid the discontinuity in the principal value (yellow branch) when crossing the negative real axis, one can maintain a winding number `w` using `WhenEvent` and use the general value of gamma:

```
γ[a_, z_?NumericQ, w_] := Exp[-2 Pi*I*w*a] Gamma[a, 0, z];

WhenEvent[Im[ψ[i][r]] > 0 && Re[ψ[i][r]] < 0, (* cross - real axis counterclockwise *)
 w[r] -> w[r] + 1,
 "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"],
WhenEvent[Im[ψ[i][r]] < 0 && Re[ψ[i][r]] < 0, (* cross - real axis clockwise *)
 w[r] -> w[r] - 1, 
 "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"]
```

This works, but crossing the branch introduces error, because the winding number is changed only at a step taken by `NDSolve`. In computing a step when the branch is crossed, it is very likely that $\gamma(a,z)$ is evaluated at points on either side of the branch.

One can move the branch cut to the positive real axis:

```
γ[a_, z_?NumericQ, w_] := Exp[-2 Pi*I*(w - UnitStep@Sign@Im[z] + 1)*a] Gamma[a, 0, z]
```

This seems to produce a better result, 
<s>perhaps because the difference between the branches seems less in magnitude there.</s> 
because it does not cross the positive real axis after the solution becomes complex.

To address the "big problem" of choosing a branch when the solution passes through the origin ne could select the branch by setting the winding number when the origin is crossed. For example, this choose the non-principal value of gamma:

```
WhenEvent[Re[ψ[i][r]] < 0 && Abs@Im[ψ[i][r]] < 1*^-8, w[r] -> 1]
```

Finally, if you want to move the initial condition to `r == 0`, that is possible, too.
$$\eqalign{
v_i'(r) &= -9\,r^2\, G1(\psi_i(r))/G1(i)\strut \cr
\psi_i'(r) &= \cases{v_i(r)/r^2 & $r \ne 0$ \cr 0 & otherwise} \cr
}$$

Code:

```
T1[i_] := {
  v'[r] == -9*r^2 G1[ψ[i][r], w[r]]/G1[i, 0],
  ψ[i]'[r] == Piecewise[{{v[r]/r^2, r != 0}}]};
```

Here's the complete approach:

```
Clear[T1, T2, T3, evts, eqn1, γ, psi2];
ϵ = 0;
a = 5/2;
γ[a_, z_?NumericQ, w_] :=          (* move branch cut to +real axis *)
  Exp[-2 Pi*I*(w - UnitStep@Sign@Im[z] + 1)*a] Gamma[a, 0, z];
G1[x_, w_] := Exp[x] γ[a, x, w];
T1[i_] := {v'[r] == -9*r^2 G1[ψ[i][r], w[r]]/G1[i, 0],
   ψ[i]'[r] == Piecewise[{{v[r]/r^2, r != 0}}]};
T2[i_] := {ψ[i][ϵ] == i};
T3[i_] := {v[ϵ] == 0, w[ϵ] == 0};
evts[i_] :=                        (* switch branch index on crossing +real axis *)
  {WhenEvent[Im[ψ[i][r]] < 0 && Re[ψ[i][r]] > 0,
    w[r] -> w[r] + 1, 
    "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"],
   WhenEvent[Im[ψ[i][r]] > 0 && Re[ψ[i][r]] > 0, 
    w[r] -> w[r] - 1,
    "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"]};
branchpt[i_, w0_] :=               (* choose branch on passing through origin *)
  WhenEvent[Re[ψ[i][r]] < 0 && Abs@Im[ψ[i][r]] < 1*^-8, w[r] -> w0];
eqn1[i_] := Join @@ Through[{T1, T2, T3, evts}[i]];

mem : psi2[bp_] := mem = Flatten@Table[
     NDSolve[{eqn1[i], branchpt[i, bp]}, ψ[i], {r, ϵ, 20},
      DiscreteVariables -> {w}, Method -> "Extrapolation"],
     {i, 1, 10}];
psi2 /@ {0, 1};
```

Imaginary parts of the two sets of solutions track opposite branches:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   *Real and imaginary parts of `ψ[i][r]` for each choice of branch (`psi2[0]`, `psi2[1]`); the real parts (blue, green) coincide, but the imaginary parts (gold, orange) have opposite signs.*
>
> ```
> Table[
>   Plot[Flatten@{ReIm[ψ[i][r] /. psi2[0]], ReIm[ψ[i][r] /. psi2[1]]} // Evaluate,
>    {r, ϵ, 20}, PlotLabel -> ψ[i], PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5}, Frame -> True],
>   {i, 10}] // Multicolumn[#, 3] &
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce your problem in *v9.0.1*, the calculation finishes in about 30 seconds, but `NDSolve` uses up its 10000 steps before `r = 20` for `i < 6`. Further check shows this problem is actually similar to this one:

[Orbit followed by a particle around Schwarzschild Black Hole](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137112/1871)

i.e. the culprit is the very small imaginary part of `G1[x]` caused by numerical error, so it can be fixed by adding a `Re` to chop the imaginary part:

```
T1 = {ψ[i]''[r] + 2/r ψ[i]'[r] == -9 Re@G1[ψ[i][r]]/G1[i]};
T2 = {ψ[i][ϵ] == i};
T3 = {ψ[i]'[ϵ] == 0};
eqn1 = {T1, T2, T3};

psi1 = 
   Table[NDSolve[eqn1, ψ[i], {r, ϵ, 20}], {i, 1, 10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.152637, Null} *)

Plot[#[[1, 1, -1]][x] & /@ psi1 // Evaluate, {x, ϵ, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]