# Shell falling into a black hole in Kruskal coordinate

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

I am modeling the motion of a shell falling into a black hole in Kruskal coordinate with `NDSolve`. I am sure that the physics behind it is correct, but can't get the desired result i.e. a smooth function defined on `{0, rWALL}`.

The code:

```
V[r_] := 1 - 100/r + r^2 - (0.16 (100/r + 1.4375 r^2)^2)/r^2
mfo[r_] := 1 - 100/r + r^2
h = 4.56978
rWALL = 6.03647
k = 13.9282
w[r_] := 1/(2 (1 + 3 h^2) Sqrt[4 + 3 h^2]) ((4 + 6 h^2) ArcTan[(h + 2 r)/Sqrt[4 + 3 h^2]] + h Sqrt[4 + 3 h^2] (2 Log[Abs[-h + r]] - Log[Abs[1 + h^2 + h r + r^2]]))
Twall[r_] := Sqrt[Xwall[r]^2 - Exp[k*w[r]]]
SolX = NDSolve[{Sqrt[(4 fo[r])/(k^2 Exp[k*w[r]])] Sqrt[-V[r]]Sqrt[(Twall'[r]^2 - Xwall'[r]^2)] == 1, Xwall[rWALL] == 1.02227}, Xwall, {r, 0, rWALL} ]
```

I only got the following warnings:

```
NDSolve::ndsdtc: The time constraint of 1.` seconds was exceeded trying to solve for derivatives, so the system will be treated as a system of differential-algebraic equations. You can use Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"} to have the system solved as ordinary differential equations. 

NDSolve::nlnum: "The function value {-1+(0. +0.00223649\ I)\ Sqrt[0. \-5.31229\Plus[<<2>>]^2]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} \at \!\({r, Xwall[r], \*SuperscriptBox[\"Xwall\", \"\[Prime]\",MultilineFunction->None][r]}\) = {6.03647,1.02227,0.}."

NDSolve::icfail: unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.
```

Can someone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more information? What are you modeling? Also, the first error from `NDSolve` seems strange. Have you set some time constraints that you didn't show in your code, or perhaps globally?

Comment: Hi I am modeling the motion of a shell in black hole spacetime in Kruskal coordinate, trying to solve the coordinate X with r (the radius of the shell) as a parameter of it. The code above is all I used to solve this problem, and I didn't set any other constraints.

Comment: I obtain a different error message, `NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.`  I recommend that you seek ways to eliminate the `Sqrt` and  `Abs`, which probably are the source of your difficulties.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I only got an interpolating function at one point 'r=rWALL' after removing the Sqrt and Abs... It is not a satisfying result.

Comment: Is `Xwall` always real?

Comment: It should always be real, if we want it to have physical meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least 3 issues here.

1. As mentioned in the comments, the `Abs` is causing trouble. If you look carefully, you'll find `Abs'` term in the equation, which can't be handled properly by `NDSolve`. This can be easily circumvented by a `Abs[a_] :> Sqrt[a^2]` replacement.
2. The coefficient of equation is too complicated, which stops `NDSolve` from transforming the equation to an… Er… explicit ODE i.e. an equation with the form $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$ in a reasonable amount of time, so the warning `ndsdtc` is generated. For more information, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109733/1871).

   `ndsdtc` isn't always a problem, because `NDSolve` will then try to solve the equation with a DAE solver, but the DAE solver of `NDSolve` is weaker than the ODE solver (at least now) and unfortunately it fails to solve your problem, so `icfail` is generated.
3. The small imaginary part generated by numeric error is troublesome. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137112/1871) is a similar problem.

The following is the fixed code:

```
Clear[V, fo, w, Twall]

Twall[r_] = Sqrt[Xwall[r]^2 - Exp[k w[r]]];
eq = Sqrt[(4 fo[r])/(k^2 Exp[k w[r]])] Sqrt[-V[r]] Sqrt[Twall'[r]^2 - Xwall'[r]^2] == 1;

neweq = Xwall'[r] == Re@Solve[eq, Xwall'[r]][[1, 1, -1]]

V[r_] = 1 - 100/r + r^2 - (0.16 (100/r + 1.4375 r^2)^2)/r^2;
fo[r_] = 1 - 100/r + r^2;
h = 4.56978;
rWALL = 6.03647;
k = 13.9282;
w[r_] = 1/(2 (1 + 3 h^2) Sqrt[
    4 + 3 h^2]) ((4 + 6 h^2) ArcTan[(h + 2 r)/Sqrt[4 + 3 h^2]] + 
     h Sqrt[4 + 3 h^2] (2 Log[Abs[-h + r]] - Log[Abs[1 + h^2 + h r + r^2]])) /. 
  Abs[a_] :> Sqrt[a^2]

SolX = NDSolveValue[{neweq, Xwall[rWALL] == 1.02227}, Xwall, {r, 0, rWALL}]

ListLinePlot@SolX
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The calculation still stops at `4.56978`, but this seems to be the nature of model?

---

## Update

OK, the singularity at $r = h$ seems to be removable. Assuming $r = h$ is a removable singularity, $X_{wall}(r)$ should be smooth around it, so $X_{wall}(h - \epsilon) \approx 2 X_{wall}(h) - X_{wall}(h + \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a small enough positive number:

```
solLeft = Block[{eps = 10^-3}, 
  NDSolveValue[Rationalize[{neweq, Xwall[h - eps] == 2 SolX[h] - SolX[h + eps]}, 0], 
   Xwall, {r, 0, h}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]]

{{rL, rR}} = solLeft["Domain"]

Plot[solLeft[r], {r, rL, rR}, PlotRange -> All]~Show~Plot[SolX[r], {r, h, rWALL}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This time the singularity at $r=0$ causes trouble so I fail to reach $r = 0$, but  I think $r=0.08$ is already acceptable?

Comment: Thanks! It is good to see a result. I think the calculation stops at that point because there exist a singularity in the function w[r] at that point. The value of w[r] at that point should be negative infinity. But one of the purpose of this calculation is to remove the influence of that singularity and get a solution defined from r=0 to r=rWALL... Now it doesn't seem very good. Do you know any method that can remove the influence of the singularity?

Comment: @Zhencheng Er… what does "remove the influence of the singularity" mean?

Comment: Well, I mean I expect to get a solution as a smooth function defined on [0,rWALL], but not only on this small region. It seems that the singularity stops the calculation to move on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But in physics, what I am trying to do is to express the equation of motion of a shell falling into a black hole in Kruksal coordinate. In this coordinate system, there is no singularity in coordinates. Everything should be smooth. So I am really confused here.

Comment: Then why not look for a reformulation (change of variables or coordinates) that won't exhibit the singularity?

Comment: @Zhencheng I retracted my former conclusion, the singularity seems to be removable, see my update.

Comment: @J.M. I can't think out one… so I turned to a simple and crude solution.

Comment: xzczd, oops, sorry, that was intended for @Zhencheng and not you, but nice workaround nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is acceptable.