# NDSolve spits out mxst warning when solving ODE defining a geodesic

Tags: differential-equations

Here is the code I'm using for my differential equation:

```
rulesDS = {L -> Sqrt[4.5], Energy -> Sqrt[0.949], b -> 1.01};
eq1 = D[r[phi], {phi, 1}] - (((r[phi]^2)/L)*
 Sqrt[(Energy^2) - (1 + (L/r[phi])^2) (1 - (1/r[phi]))]);
eq1n = eq1 /. rulesDS;
solDS1N = NDSolve[{eq1n == 0, r[0] == 1.01}, r, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

However, I keep getting the following warning:

```
NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 169391 steps reached at the point phi == 1.7415891878263994`.
```

The equation I'm trying to solve is equation 3 in the attached image with `δ = 1`.

[image]

Comment: What is $\delta$ in the original equation? Is there a reason for introducing the square roots instead of just writing the equation with the same powers as shown in the book?

Comment: Worst title ever... could apply to nearly every question ever posted here.

Comment: I've modified the title for you, please make a bit more effort in writing an informative title next time.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I'd like to point out you're not solving exactly the same equation in screenshot, the original equation should be:

```
eq = D[r[phi], phi]^2 == 
     (r[phi]^4 (Energy^2 - (1 + (L/r[phi])^2)  (1 - 1/r[phi])))/L^2
```

The LHS of `eq` is a bit troublesome, we need to help `NDSolve` a bit. A possible solution is to differentiate the ODE once:

```
ic = r[0] == 101/100;
icadd = Equal @@@ Flatten@Solve[eq /. phi -> 0 /. Rule @@ ic, r'[0]]

sollst = NDSolveValue[{D[eq, phi], ic, #} /. rulesDS, r, {phi, 0, 2  π}] & /@ 
  icadd

sollst // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Alternatively, force `NDSolve` to use the DAE solver with proper `DefaultStartingValue` setting:

```
sollst = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic} /. rulesDS, r, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
       "DAEInitialization" -> {"Collocation", 
         "DefaultStartingValue" -> #}}] & /@ {1, -1};
sollst // ListPlot
```

[image]

BTW, I believe this problem is somewhat related to the following:

[Orbit followed by a particle around Schwarzschild Black Hole](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137112/1871)

But sadly the method therein doesn't work well on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Following the help you can either try increasing number of steps or reduce accuracy goal. This works

```
 solDS1N=NDSolve[{eq1n==0,r[0]==1.01},r,{phi,0,2 Pi},AccuracyGoal->3]
```

with no errors.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See help under `ref/message/NDSolve/mxst`

Another option is to use

```
solDS1N=NDSolve[{eq1n==0,r[0]==1.01},r,{phi,0,2 Pi},Method->"StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which also completes with no error. It looks like your ode is stiff ode.

Comment: Sadly the solution doesn't seem to be correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The proper solution built-in is

```
DSolve[(r'[ \[Phi]])^2 == 
      r[ \[Phi]]^4/L^2 (W^2 - (\[Delta] + L^2/r[ \[Phi]]^2) (1 - 1/r[ \[Phi]])), r[ \[Phi]], \[Phi]].
```

You give a nonlinear differential equation of first order.

DSolve[eqn,u,x]
solves a differential equation for the function u, with independent variable x.

The output is very long

[image: output of the nonlinear differential equation.]

I am sorry that I am not able to copy'n'paste the true Mathematica output. It should be easy to enter my input line. Mathematica needs some moment to compute the solution.

The solution is rather difficult. I have not entered any of the parameters You give. This is the most general solution possible with Mathematica.

You have to calculate the `Solve` built-ins that are given and ready to compute with Your preferred parameters.

Most important is to understand why this works. So this is a nonlinear differential equation. The nonlinearity is quadratic and the equation is homogeneous. So this is the differential equation for the elliptic function `EllipticF`. Ask for example WolframAlpha for a short definition.

My answer is flexible and has the generativity to explore the problem properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
  (dr/d\[Phi])^2 == r^4/L^2 (W^2 - (\[Delta] + L^2/r^2) (1 - 1/r))
```

This is the equation of a first integral of the trajectory $r(\phi)$ with energy parameter $E=W$, angular momentum $L$, by the conservation of mass-energy, angular momentum $L$ and elimination of time and proper time as curve parameter in space-time.

The strategy is clear, algebraically, separate in terms of $r$ and $\phi$:

```
 Solve[(dr/d\[Phi])^2 == 
      r^4/L^2 (W^2 - (\[Delta] + L^2/r^2) (1 - 1/r)), d\[Phi]]
```

$$sol=\int \mathbb d\phi \to  \int \frac{  L}{\sqrt{-L^2 r^2+L^2 r-\delta  r^4+r^4 W^2+\delta  r^3}}\mathbb d r$$
that can be simplified to
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{ r^4 \ \frac{W^2-\delta}{L^2}+ r^3 \ \frac{\delta }{L^2}-r^2+r}} \, dr$$

Its a quadratic equation between the differentials, so its the best way to present the solution in squares, too. Decisions for the choice of signs in the square roots can be done for a numerical set of the parameters. The indices  of the four roots $r_n$ are symbolically, free for permutations.

```
    Assuming[
   Subscript[r, 1] < r < Subscript[r, 2] < Subscript[r, 3] < 
     Subscript[r, 4],
    FullSimplify[(sol /. {Root[_, n_] -> Subscript[r, n]})^2 ]]
```

$$\phi ^2=\frac{\left(4 L^2 \left(r r_1-1\right) \left(r r_2-1\right) \left(r r_3-1\right)\right) F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_3-\frac{1}{r}}{r_3-r_2}}\right)|\frac{r_2-r_3}{r_1-r_3}\right){}^2}{\left(r_1-r_3\right) \left(L^2 (r-1)-r^2 \left(\delta +r \left(W^2-\delta \right)\right)\right)}$$

Numerically, its no problem to invert to $\phi \to r(\phi)$

Mathematical implications: for a hyperbolic trajectory, positive energy parameter, the angle as a functions of radius is unique invertible between a perihel and any of both directions of infinity. For W<0 and impact parameter L large enough to avoid collision with the  center, there are two half periods between peri- and aphel angles. The solution is a Kepler elipse with a rotating axis, the typical feature of elliptic functions, that are periodic in time but not periodic in angle and not very harmonical with an infinite  hramonic series.

For impact parameter $L$ too small, the solution is an inward or outward monotone  spiral.

Tabular: Gradshteyn/Rhyzik prensents this most general elliptic integral as a series of definite integrals on the real line with one of the 6 singular points a supper or lower limit $$\int_a^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\prod_{n=1}^4(r-r_n)}},  a\in \left(-\infty,r_n \right)$$
or
$$\int^a_x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\prod_{n=1}^4(r-r_n)}},   a\in \left( r_n, \infty\right)$$
No pair of these integrals are similar in form. Its the deep mystery of elliptic curves, that they represent the same integral.

Any of these integrals yield a  different class of trajectories, in the euclidean case $\delta=0$ there are only the three conic sections left.

Similar to Goldstein, Classical Mechanics, Kepler problem, analyze the quartic for reasonable values of the parameters and find the intervals between its roots as r-intervals, yielding positive values of $\phi'(r)^2$

This is one of the extremal points that can be reached by a mathematically talented student in classical analytical mechanics.

Mathematicas Simplify, ComplexExpand, FunctionExpand etc. will not be very helpful, its implementation of the algebra of elliptic integrals and functions is rudimentary to nonexistent, see Help.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2:

Another way is to consider next order of ode, to avoid singularity at last point as found below.

Abbreviate $t=\phi ,~L=len~$,let $ \delta=1 , r=r(t), E=energ $

```
$$r'= \frac{r^2}{len}(energ-(1-len^2/r^2(1-1/r))$$
$$ r'[t]= \frac{r^2 energ^2}{l}-\frac{r^2-l^2}{l}\frac{r-1}{r}$$
Differentiate wrt $t$and simplify
$$ len (\frac{r r''}{r'})+r'=3r^2(energ^2-1)+(l^2+2r)$$
{ri, len, energ, tmax} = {1.01, Sqrt[4.5], Sqrt[0.949], 12};
rdi = ri^2/len*(energ^2 - (1 - len^2/ri^2)*(1 - 1/ri));
NDSolve[{len (r[t] r''[t]/r'[t] + r'[t]) == 
    3 r[t]^2 (energ^2 - 1) + (len^2 + 2 r[t]), r'[0] == rdi, 
   r[0] == 1.01}, r, {t, 0, tmax}];
rad[t_] = r[t] /. First[%];
Plot[{rad[t], rad'[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Green}}]
```

$r[t], r'[t]$ (red,green) solution curves plotted against $t= \phi.$ An asymptotic behavior is noted.

[image]

EDIT1:

It works for me until crash/ singularity:

```
{len, energ, phimax} = {Sqrt[4.5], Sqrt[0.949], 1.6486};
eq1n = D[r[phi], {phi, 1}] - (((r[phi]^2)/len)*
     Sqrt[(energ^2) - (1 + (len/r[phi])^2) (1 - (1/r[phi]))]);
NDSolve[{eq1n == 0, r[0] == 1.01}, r, {phi, 0, phimax}];
rad[t_] = r[t] /. First[%];
Plot[rad[phi], {phi, 0, phimax}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]